# What is the purpose of accessing a global variable with this.variable across my servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, oop, servlets

This is the sample servlet

```
public class XYZServlet extends HttpServlet {
 public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
 protected long a = -1;
 protected String str = null;
 protected responseJSON = null;

 public XYZServlet() {
   super();
 }

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //initialization of global variables goes here
    this.a = request.getParameter("serial_number");
    this.str = this.utilMethod();

    //and the rest of the code goes here
    PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter();
    pout.write("Success!");
 }

 protected String utilMethod () {

    //this returns some string after executiion
 }
}
```

> 1. What advantage we have on declaring the variables as protected here rather than public?
> 2. What is the purpose of accessing the variables with this.variable across the servlet?
> 3. What is the purpose of creating a non-parameterized constructor invoking parent constructor from it? Is there any specific reason or
>      structural logic behind this?

*Because when a servlet gets initialized by a web server it gets initialized with a default constructor invoking its parent constructor by calling super() similar to one shown above - by default.*

> 4.Is there any better way to initialize these global variables in the above servlet?

*The global variables in the above servlet contains values like*

- request parameter values and
- values from util methods inside this servlet

Comment: This servlet is **wrong** in every possible way. A servlet can receive multiple requests simultaneously, on different threads - this servlet is essentially written be a race hazard. Please delete it and start again.

Comment: To answer your specific questions. 1) all variables should always be `private` unless they're `public static final`. 2) this is the main problem, you cannot have global variables in a servlet, not unless you know what you are going. 3) this serves no purpose whatsoever. 4) don't.

Comment: 2) Does accessing the variable by this.variable makes it consistent across requests?

Comment: No. Because a) there is no memory barrier and b) because you set it _in a_ request. P.S. if you do not know with a) means then you probably should not be dealing with multithreaded Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already commented the usage of fields in a servlet is dead wrong; concurrent access, servlet reuse and such.

The solution for a kind of reuse, is to provide a simple POJO (plain old java object) that can be reused in the servlets. That object can have those fields, and be created on the doPost/doGet.

---

```
class Util {
    long a = -1;
    String str = null;
    responseJSON = null;

    String someMethod();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //initialization of pojo goes here
    Util pojo = new Util();
    pojo .a = request.getParameter("serial_number");
    pojo .str = this.utilMethod();
    .... pojo.someMethod();

     //and the rest of the code goes here
     PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter();
     pout.write("Success!");
 }

 protected String utilMethod () {

     //this returns some string after executiion
 }
```

Comment: Really a nice approach Joop Eggen - like creating a simple POJO during doGet/doPost and having all my fields in it.

But in my case I need the object fields to be accessed across the util methods too.. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks a lot Joop Eggen and Boris the Spider.

Answer (score 1):

1. `public` variables can be accessed anywhere, `protected` can be accessed in the same package or if you move out of package then only in child class.
2. `this` refers to current object. If you have same name for *instance variable and local variable* in a method then this.variable will point to instance variable. In your code you do not have same name of variables so you can omit using `this` there.
3. As you are not having any code lines in the constructor, so you can omit it. Compiler will automatically add it.
4. As you are initializing variables from the request's parameters, so you will have to do it in either `doPost` or `doGet` method.

Comment: This doesn't really cover _why_ a servlet cannot store global variables. There is a large and apparent multithreading issue with the code, and the other questions are somewhat meaningless until the OP understands that.